# Spring Security + jQuery: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have trouble in coupling Spring Security authentication with jQuery. Actually script does not even run - nothing happens when i click on 
In browser's console i found message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in login.js:1.

I've read some questions answered earlier and realised that this is problem concerning wrong ContentType returned, but i don't know how to fix it. I think that it may be also linked to Spring Security resource protection. I added config line posted below to turn it off, that made at least css working.

It is also weird that when i go to Sources in console, then click on login.js html code appears rather than js code.

I kindly ask for help with putting it all together :)

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        var email = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
// Checking for blank fields.
        if( email =='' || password ==''){
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border","2px solid red");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow","0 0 3px red");
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        }else {
            $.post("login",{username: email, password: password},
                function(data) {
                    if(data=='Invalid Email.......') {
                        $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
                        $('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                        alert(data);
                    }else if(data=='Email or Password is wrong...!!!!'){
                        $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
                        alert(data);
                    } else if(data=='Successfully Logged in...'){
                        $("form")[0].reset();
                        $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                        alert(data);
                    } else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login page</h1>
<form>
    <label for="username">Username</label>:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus"/> <br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input type="button" id="login" value="Log in"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@Controller
public class Login {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/homepage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homepage() {
    return "homepage";
}
```

}

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
            = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html");
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
}
}
```

EDIT:
When i deleted invocation of anyRequest(); method in web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest(); there is another error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/login.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is 
not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: You should provide all your `spring-security` config and any log messages relevant

Comment: i added security config snippet to question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that maybe the trouble is due to `csrf`. There is a snippet where in fact it is, but I think that in your `jquery` `post` you are not sending it.

The `Unexpected token <` message could be due to CSRFFilter sending html encoded `http` `401` or `403` response.

You could make a try disabling `csrf` in security configuration to check wether it works or not, and if it finally works this way, then you could make the proper changes to turn it on without breaking the `login` `post`

Comment: I added csrf().disable() to my HttpSecurity configuration, but still no luck. All responses have code 200. It's weird, cause when i click on login.js script in dev tools appears html code. I don't get it - why?

Answer (score 0):

We must pass header and tokens in all post request,

```
             var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"); 

               var header = 
               $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

          xhttp.setRequestHeader(header, token);
          xhttp.send();
```

Comment: I disabled anti-csrf protection, but still it doesn't work. I think there is a problem with encoding or something. In dev tools when i click on login.js script appears html code. Why?